# Unable to find by class name

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract data in `<div class="user-profile_list __relatives">` ... (see image)

Source code of the page https://gist.github.com/mascai/59e3bf779c2ba7cecb973ab9653ed419

My code

```
def get_relatives(driver):
    relatives = []
    relatives_container = driver.find_element_by_class_name("user-profile_list __relatives")
    return relatives

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
get_relatives(driver)
```

Error text

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".user-profile_list __relatives"}

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This thing happens many time, its better to use xpath and search for class in it,

```
relatives_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[class="classuser-profile_list __relatives"]')
```

You can also try contains in xpath, it also work if there are multiple classes in that element and write only one of them

```
relatives_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, 'user-profile_list __relatives')]')
```